# linkedin: Message not getting posted

Tags: java, android, linkedin-api

I'm doing linkedin integration for sharing the data in android, after giving the username and password and clicked on "sign in and allow" button i'm not able to move to the next page instead coming back to the previous page, and also data not posted on the wall, i tried out many tutorials, links, but could not findout my mistake and struggling alot, can anyone please help me.
here's my MainActivity code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public static final String CONSUMER_KEY             = "key";
public static final String CONSUMER_SECRET          = "secret";    
public static final String APP_NAME                 = "rebuix";
public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME    = "x-oauthflow-linkedin";
public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST      = "litestcalback";
public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL       = OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME + "://"   +    OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST;


LinkedInOAuthService oAuthService = LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory
        .getInstance().createLinkedInOAuthService(CONSUMER_KEY,
                CONSUMER_SECRET);
LinkedInApiClientFactory factory = LinkedInApiClientFactory
        .newInstance(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
LinkedInRequestToken liToken;
LinkedInApiClient client;


@SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi" })
Button btnLinkedin;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new   StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    Button btnLinkedinMain = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkedin);
    btnLinkedinMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnLinkedin) {

        oAuthService = LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory.getInstance()
                .createLinkedInOAuthService(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY,
                        Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
        System.out.println("oAuthService : " + oAuthService);

        factory = LinkedInApiClientFactory.newInstance(
                Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);

        liToken = oAuthService
                .getOAuthRequestToken(Constants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(liToken
                .getAuthorizationUrl()));

        i.putExtra( "sms_body", false );
        try
        { 
                       startActivity(i);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        // Display some sort of error message here.
    }
    }
}

protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {


    try {
        linkedInImport(intent);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void linkedInImport(Intent intent) {
    String verifier = intent.getData().getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
    System.out.println("liToken " + liToken);
    System.out.println("verifier " + verifier);

    LinkedInAccessToken accessToken = oAuthService.getOAuthAccessToken(
            liToken, verifier);
    client = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);

    // client.postNetworkUpdate("LinkedIn Android app test");

    Person profile = client.getProfileForCurrentUser(EnumSet.of(
            ProfileField.ID, ProfileField.FIRST_NAME,
            ProfileField.LAST_NAME, ProfileField.HEADLINE));

    System.out.println("First Name :: " + profile.getFirstName());
    System.out.println("Last Name :: " + profile.getLastName());
    System.out.println("Head Line :: " + profile.getHeadline());

};

    });
}
    }
```

Comment: Hi , Please download the latest code from http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/source/checkout  . If you still find any issue, please post your message on issue form , we will help you out.

Comment: i had downloaded that code also, but still getting force close@vineet

Comment: Hi, please open your issue in socialauth issue log. we will try to solve it.

Comment: Hi , Can you please post your issue in socialauth issue list.

Answer (score 0):

try out this tutorial...you will get message post feature in this tutorial..and for step by step integration in your app see this link... http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/wiki/Linkedin

https://github.com/srivastavavivek1987/LinkedIn-Connection-in-Android

Comment: i tried this link also http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/wiki/Linkedin, but after downloading and running the project gets force close@Mehul Ranpara

Comment: first download code from this link...https://github.com/srivastavavivek1987/LinkedIn-Connection-in-Android